# How to quickly test if a URL exists and has content in java?

Tags: java, performance, url, timeout

I am looking to test to see if hundreds of URLs exist, and the current way I have takes too much time. This is what I have found so far:

```
public static boolean checkURL(URL u)
{
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
try
{
  connection = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
  connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
  int code = connection.getResponseCode();
  System.out.println("" + code);
  // You can determine on HTTP return code received. 200 is success.
  if (code == 200)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
catch (MalformedURLException e)
{
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  // e.printStackTrace();
  System.out.println("error");
}
catch (IOException e)
{
  System.out.println("error2");
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  // e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
  if (connection != null)
  {
    connection.disconnect();
}
}

return false;
}
```

Although this does successfully find whether a URL exists and has content, it does so in a lengthy period of time, with the program often taking upwards of five minutes to execute. Does anyone know more efficient ways to test this?

Note: It is important to test that not only the url returns 200, but also that the website doesn't timeout.

Comment: How can you test that a website doesn't time out without waiting for it to time out?

Comment: It seems to me that pinging takes a lot less time than this method, although I'm unsure on how to execute that

Comment: Did you try [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+ping)?

Comment: I did, when I found questions about pinging websites and tried the solutions, the program still returned sites that timed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good and it should be the easiest way to check for url. You might want to add a ***timeout*** in the HttpURLConnection.

Sample code for reference.

```
enter code here
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class UrlChecker {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println(URLExists("http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/delay/
3000/url/http://www.google.co.uk"));
}

public static boolean URLExists(String targetUrl) {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new 
        URL(targetUrl).openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        // Set timeouts 2000 in milliseconds and throw exception
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(2000);
       /* Set timeouts 4000 in milliseconds and it should work as the url 
        should return back in 3 seconds.
        httpUrlConn.setConnectTimeout(4000);
        httpUrlConn.setReadTimeout(4000);
        */
        System.out.println("Response Code =>"+ 
        urlConnection.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println("Response Msg =>"+ 
        urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
        return (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 
        HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception => " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
}
```